# Magento 2 : How to add Conditional Links in Layout?

Tags: magento2.2.3, page-layouts

I've added my custom link to `top.links` using **layout.xml**

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="something-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Create Something</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Route/Controller/index</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**One More I've added at Customer Account Page**

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="something-name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">route/controller/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Something</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> 1. First Link which is at `top.links` I would like to only show if customer is logged in.
>
>    2. Second will only display if customer is in Customer Group That is **Wholesale**.

How can i achieve this ???

Any Ideas ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `top.links` and `customer_account_navigation` you can create your Block class Instead of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current` and add your condition there, like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Block\Link" name="something-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Create Something</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Route/Controller/index</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Now you need to create your own block class,

`YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Block\Link` which should extends extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

and in this class you can add your condition in `_toHtml()` function for example,

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (something) { // here you can add your custom condition
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
```

---

**Example**,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="StackExchange\Test\Block\Link" name="something-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Create Something</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Route/Controller/index</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Block file,

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Test\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface;


class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link implements SortLinkInterface
{

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (check login condition) { // replace with your condition
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::SORT_ORDER);
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem, There's one little help needed, I would like to add `css_class` to new link at account side bar, I added using ` <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">nav item</argument>` Dont know why its not working, I checked `vendor` they used same as i did. Any ideas ?!!

Comment: how to get customer session class in __construct because its throwing error when we used __construct 
  
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
         $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        }