# How to show Block depending on Customer Logged In/Out in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, customer-session

I want to Show Conditionally Depend on customer logged-in status

For Magento 1 I Found this Solution I want the Same Topic for Magento 2

```
// is Logged in
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="name_of_reference_block">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block_name">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>block_id</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

// is Not Logged IN

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="name_of_reference_block">
        <remove name="name_of_block_to_remove"></remove>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224463/magento-2-how-to-add-conditional-links-in-layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know is it a right way, but you can write a simple module which will add similar handles:

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Plugins -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout">
        <plugin name="add_customer_status_handle_to_layout"
                type="MageWorx\CustomerLayoutHandle\Plugin\AddCustomerStatusHandle"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/Plugin/AddCustomerStatusHandle.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\CustomerLayoutHandle\Plugin;


class AddCustomerStatusHandle
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * AddCustomerStatusHandle constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout
     */
    public function afterAddDefaultHandle(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $result
    ) {
        if ($this->customerSession->getCustomerId()) {
            $result->addHandle('customer_logged_in');
        } else {
            $result->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

When layout is loading it always load default handle using method `addDefaultHandle()`, so you can write a plugin for that method and check customer session to detect a suitable type of customer handle. This approach compatible with full page cache, because the customer group id exists in the cache key, so unlogged customers have the 0 group id and call another version of cached page.

Remember that the string you provide to `addHandle` corresponds to an xml file with the same name in `app/code/Your/Plugin/view/frontend/layout/`
So if you do `$result->addHandle('foo_bar');` then you need to make a layout file `app/code/Your/Plugin/view/frontend/layout/foo_bar.xml`

Here the [complete code of example on GitHub](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/MageWorx_CustomerLayoutHandle) with block for test purposes. You can use it with only one modifications - please, remove default layouts and templates, because it rendering on each page of Magento.

Here a how I tested it:

Code structure:

[image: code structure]

There is two different layouts for different cases: logged in customer and guest customer, with 2 regular template blocks having 2 different templates.

For logged in customer:

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/view/frontend/layout/customer_logged_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="logged_out" before="-" template="MageWorx_CustomerLayoutHandle::logged_in.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/view/frontend/templates/logged_in.phtml

```
<h3><?= __('Logged In');?></h3>
```

For guest customer:

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/view/frontend/layout/customer_logged_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="logged_out" before="-" template="MageWorx_CustomerLayoutHandle::logged_out.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/view/frontend/templates/logged_out.phtml

```
<h3><?= __('Logged Out');?></h3>
```

Here the result on frontend for **logged in customer**:

[image: result for logged in customer]

And for a **Guest customer**:

[image: result for guest customer]

#### Update:

---

In case you need that update only on the category view page we can add another plugin for the `Layout` class:

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerLayoutHandle/Plugin/AddCustomerStatusHandle.php

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $subject
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $result
 */
public function afterAddHandle(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $subject,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $result,
    $handleName
) {
    if ($handleName == 'catalog_category_view') {
        $availableHandles = $result->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
        if ($this->customerSession->getCustomerId() &&
            !in_array('catalog_category_view_customer_logged_in', $availableHandles)
        ) {
            $result->addHandle('catalog_category_view_customer_logged_in');
        } elseif (!in_array('catalog_category_view_customer_logged_out', $availableHandles)) {
            $result->addHandle('catalog_category_view_customer_logged_out');
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and after cleaning a cache we can use the two new handles: `catalog_category_view_customer_logged_in` and `catalog_category_view_customer_logged_out` which is available only when the default `catalog_category_view` handle exists in layout update.

Code structure for test (2 layouts with two new different templates like in first example):

[image: code structure]

Logged out customer on the category view page:

[image: Logged out customer on the category view page]

Logged in customer on the category view page:

[image: Logged in customer on the category view page]

Logged in customer on the home page (block for category page does not exist):

[image: Logged in customer on the home page]

Comment: thanks for your reply i got your answer.. but if i want to add some blocks in `catalog_cateory_view`  ... you have only added this is default.xml please Guide me

Comment: @WaqarAli Thank you for comment, I will try to update module to obtain desired result.

Comment: Thank You i am waiting for your answer

Comment: @WaqarAli I've update my answer and code on github, feel free to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau does this solution work with Varnish as well?

Comment: @Radu did not tested

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau tested successfully on Varnish 6. Thanks for the elegant solution.